# In-order access to shared resource in python3 Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Given the MWE below:

```
import multiprocessing

def thread_function(shared_resource : dict, val : int) -> None: 

    if val not in shared_resource.keys(): 
        print(f"Value {val} is not in keys!")
        shared_resource[val] = 1

    shared_resource[val] += 1

def main():

    no_of_threads = 5
    manager       = multiprocessing.Manager()
    
    shared_resource = manager.dict()

    values = [1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]

    with multiprocessing.Pool(no_of_threads) as pool:

        pool.starmap(thread_function,
                     [ (shared_resource, val) for val in values], 
                     chunksize=1)

    print(shared_resource)


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I am having a `readers/writers` issue that I don't know how to resolve. The dictionary is a shared resource amongst the threads and I wish for the access to it to be atomic i.e., to avoid the scenario where two threads try to write the same value to it. For instance here is an incorrect output:

```
Value 1 is not in keys!
Value 1 is not in keys! # <-- Nope! 
Value 2 is not in keys!
Value 3 is not in keys!
Value 4 is not in keys!
Value 5 is not in keys!
```

On the other hand, there is the possibility that the threads will access the resource in the correct order and the output will be the correct one i.e.,

```
Value 1 is not in keys!
Value 2 is not in keys!
Value 3 is not in keys!
Value 4 is not in keys!
Value 5 is not in keys!
{1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

But how can I avoid such scenarios and always have them behave as expected? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Driven by your typical ironic comment I presume I am missing something CRIMINALLY obvious or I am unable to read.

Comment: my apologies, I missed the fact that you were indeed using a synchronized data structure. There is however still a delay between checking if your dict contains a value and adding a new one which leads to the race condition you observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it exactly criminal, but I would call it malpractice.

Your code in `thread_function` constitutes a *critical section* whose execution needs to be *serialized* so that only a single process can be executing it at a time. Even what appears to be a single statement, `shared_resource[val] += 1`, consists of multiple bytecode instructions and two processes could read the same initial value of `shared_resource[val]` and store the same updated value. But clearly multiple processed running in parallel could clearly find that there are no keys in the dictionary and will be storing identical keys.

```py
import multiprocessing

def init_processes(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def thread_function(shared_resource : dict, val : int) -> None:

    with lock:
        if val not in shared_resource.keys():
            print(f"Value {val} is not in keys!")
            shared_resource[val] = 1

        shared_resource[val] += 1

def main():

    no_of_threads = 5
    manager       = multiprocessing.Manager()

    shared_resource = manager.dict()

    values = [1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(no_of_threads, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:

        pool.starmap(thread_function,
                     [ (shared_resource, val) for val in values],
                     chunksize=1)

    print(shared_resource)


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Prints:

```None
Value 1 is not in keys!
Value 2 is not in keys!
Value 3 is not in keys!
Value 5 is not in keys!
Value 4 is not in keys!
{1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 4, 5: 2, 4: 2}
```

**NOTE**: *You have no control, however, over the dispatching of the tasks and therefore cannot control the order in which the keys will be stored.*

Comment: Aren't the duplications stemming from the non-atomicity of existence check (`if val in ...`) and initialization (`shared_resource[val] = 1`), rather than the `+= 1`?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes, of course. That's why I put the locking not just around the increment (`+= 1`) statement. I specifically citied the increment statement saying that *even* that *single* statement is really multiple bytecode statements, and thus not atomic. I sort of assumed that it was obvious that the the two-statement initialization sequence was not atomic. Perhaps I should have been explicit about that and used the actual word *atomic*.